# 301 Redirect Images Directory Structure - Static Site To Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image, .htaccess, redirect

I am re-building a static HTML website into Wordpress. The images directory structure is changing so I need to set-up 301 redirects - for Google Image searches so they keep working and point to the new image locations.

The images are currently using the static site /images/ directory.

```
/images/img1.jpg  
/images/img2.jpg  
/images/img3.jpg
```

I need them to 301 redirect to the Wordpress site /wp-content/uploads/ directory.

```
/wp-content/uploads/img1.jpg  
/wp-content/uploads/img2.jpg  
/wp-content/uploads/img3.jpg
```

Is there a single line of htaccess code that can redirect all of the images in the /images/ directory to their respective locations in the new /wp-content/uploads/ directory?

Comment: Why not just leave the images in the images folder, and use wp-content for new ones?

Comment: Sorry do you mean simply create an /images/ directory at root level and pull them in from their, rather than try and upload them into the Wordpress media folder?